# find the sub-string that contains at least 5 and at most 6 dots

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
Info : sub-strings are separated by spaces within the string.

Mission : find the sub-string that contains at least 5 and at most 6 dots.

Catch : there is no specific order to the dots that are mixed within the sub-strings.
```

In the example below.. the output should be.. "`d...d..d`" because it is the first match that will satisfy the "at least 5 dots and at most 6 dots" criteria.

```
$string = "a.a.a b.b..b c..c..c d...d..d e.e";
$pattern = "_not_known_";
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
echo "/n";
```

desired output :

```
d...d..d
```

Comment: Shouldn't be hard with [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) and [substr_count](https://www.php.net/substr-count). What did you try?

Comment: @Koala Yeung, because what if there is a million sub-strings ? would it be efficient to `explode()` and and then check one by one ? can't `preg_match()` do this on it's own ? does `preg_match()` do the same thing behind the scenes ? does it `explode()` and check one by one ?

Comment: How about " ..... " ? Should that be matched (excluding the blanks)?

Comment: @Yunnosch, I could not find any examples on "google" search. No-body seems to have discussed an issue like this. in other words for "`string or word that contains at least ____`" .

Comment: @Yunnosch, there is no feature on StackOverflow to add "money offer" to a question that you ask, If there was such feature.. I would have included perhaps "1 dollar" to this question and the chosen answer either by myself or the user voters.. would have gotten the share of that "1 dollar".

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the questions here are not for making paid job offers either. They are exclusively for finding help with your own programming. You are however the first one to actually offer money, I like that. My respect. However, 1 dollar is probably something which most users here scoff at.

Comment: The users here cannot "reprocuce" the problem of wanting to hire a decent programmer for 1 dollar. So I am voting to close the question. Please don't take this wrong, I had to select one of the reasons offered by the system. Alternatively, the question could be seen as "too broad", because there is not specific problem in programming you are asking for help with, you only want your requirements covered in any way. Sorry.

Comment: @Yunnosch, if the cheapest cloud server costs 4 dollars a month, that means 1 dollar rents that cloud server for about 7 days.

Comment: Apart from that, for your future quesitons, allow me the hint that clarification questions like mine concerning "...." should be answered to get answers which match your needs.

Comment: If renting a cloud server solves your problem, then do so. If you need a human to find out what you exactly want and then do the work for you, I guess you will need to offer more somewhere else or play by the rules here to get it for free. Actually I already wrote an answer, which is invisible for you. So I did the work already and for free, but I cannot show it to you while you don't play by the rules.

Comment: By the way, none of the downvotes is by me.

Comment: @Yunnosch, oh. ok. sorry. please forgive.

Comment: @Yunnosch , perhaps people that are stuck in expensive countries.. need a-lot of money in order to survive and live. but perhaps in Africa.. there may be cheap or free land.. you can build your own house with hay and mud. or with sticks and mud. if the internet could be cheap also.. you could look at "1 dollar" as "a-lot of money".  it is all about an "equation" .. and "efficiency".

Comment: This is not about the price, it is about StackOverflow having a completely different idea. If you do not program yourself, this is not for you.

Comment: Starting this specific branch of programming does not require any special environment. Begin your first experiments here: https://regex101.com There you can try and see your results and it has all the explanation you need to get first results. When you have anything even approaching what you are trying to do you are set to come back here. That will take less time than the two of us have already spent discussing this. Start with `\w*\.`.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I did not know there was an "idea" going on here on StackOverflow. I thought it as about asking a question and trying to find an answer about programming. I guess there is something going on here that I do not even know what it is about. very strange world to me.

Comment: Well, you did not take the [tour], though you promised to do so when creating your account. Probably did not read [ask] either. So that might be the reason why you do not know about how this site is meant to be used.

Comment: @Yunnosch, there are lots of web sites on the internet with "terms of service" type of pages. they use a-lot of complex words, a-lot of newly invented words, it is impossible for me to read and make sense of those things, I usually skip them so that I can live my life rather than waste my life.

Comment: @Yunnosc, it was due to lack of rules that the universe probably came into existence, the only rule is perhaps the "possible" element. Perhaps the only rule that is above me is the "possible" element. I have no choice but to respect that rule or "law". everything else is below it. it over-rules everything. it over-powers everything. it is too powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your answer don't need regex so here you go.

```
$string = "a.a.a b.b..b c..c..c d...d..d e.e.....";
$string = explode(' ', $string); //Split a string by space
$result = null;

for ($i=0; $i < count($string); $i++) {
    $dots = substr_count($string[$i], '.'); //Count dot in string
    if ($dots == 5 || $dots ==6 ) {
        $result = $string[$i];
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: 1. You ignore OPs comments that they believe this to be inefficient 2. This is almost a code-only answer, lacks a detailed explanation 3. Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is meant to provide programming work done free of charge. 4. Don't forget to claim the offered 1 dollar for your work.

Comment: Although I was hoping for a "pure-ly preg_match() only method" .. this answer is still "something" because I can use this in the future to ask questions. at least I can use it to show it to people to prove that " I have made some efforts" because some people might ask " show us your efforts " and I do not want my skin to turn red or pink. it would be less embarrassing if i show them some codes.

Comment: It should also be noted that I actually do not know.. if it is possible for there to be a `"preg_match()" only` version to this.

Answer (score 1):

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FRpDR)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ChS4uR/1))

```
$string = "a.a.a b.b..b c....c....c d...d..d e.e";

echo preg_match('~(?<=^|\s)([a-z])(?:\.\1?){5,6}\1(?=$|\s)~', $string, $match) ? $match[0] : 'no match';
```

Output:

```
d...d..d
```

Pattern Breakdown:

```
~                 # pattern's starting delimiter
(?<=^|\s)         # lookbehind to ensure that match is preceded by no characters or a whitespace
([a-z])           # capture a single letter as "capture group #1"
(?:\.\1?){5,6}    # match a single dot, then optionally the same letter from capture group #1; repeat ONLY 5 or 6 times
\1                # match the letter from capture group #1 to ensure that the sequence ends how it starts
(?=$|\s)          # lookahead to ensure that match is followed by no characters or a whitespace
~                 # pattern's ending delimiter
```